# Rename screen for xrandr

Tags: xrandr

I have issues setting up my screens with xrandr.

This is my xrandr output:

```
DP-0.8 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    29.97    25.00    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1200x960      59.90  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected 2560x1440+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1080     60.00    24.00  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

As you can see, for some reason unbeknownst to me, one of my screens gets identified as **DP-0.8**. The dot causes issues in xrandr scripts such as Xsetup which I want to use to swap my screens in SDDM.

I have two questions that are so closely related that I think they are legal to ask in the same post:

- Why is this happening? I have not seen any example of a screen getting designated a float instead of an integer anywhere.
- How can I change this (i.e. changing DP-0.8 to DP-5)?

Comment: I don't think you can change the names of what `xrandr` identifies, but you can (and - if you're right - should) open a bug against sddm if it contains scripts that don't work on all the possible outputs of `xrandr`.

Comment: I would be trawling though the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/*` files as well as the output of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` as to why there is a `DP-0.8`. You also need to edit the question and tell us your screen setup.